# Return List<this>

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, .net-4.5

Is it possible to use `this.GetType()` as the type of a `List`?
I have the following `class` that is inherited by several objects:

```
public class MainRepository
{
    // ??? should be the type of this
    public List<???> GetAll()
    {
        return new List<???>();
    }
}
```

I know it can be done as a generic method like this:

```
    public List<T> GetAll<T>()
    {
        return new List<T>();
    }
```

But I wonder if it can be done without explicitly defining the type in the calling method.

Comment: You can always define the list as `List<object>` and then cast the items to whatever type you want.

Comment: Why not using static method to return class type ? public static List<MainRepository> GetAll()

Comment: What is wrong with the generic approach?

Comment: You can make your class itself generic `public class MainRepository<T>` which should then let you change the method to `public List<T> GetAll()` but I don't think there's any other way.

Comment: The return type has to be defined at compile time. So the only possible soultion would be to return either List<object>, object or dynamic. The generic approach is preferred.

Comment: @EmilLundin You cannot use IList<object> since IList<> does not allow covariance (for a very good reason). However, I agree dynamic is also a good option.

Comment: Is an extension method an option for you? How to you populate the list?  This looks more like querying the IoC-Container ...

Comment: What larger problem are you trying to solve? Why not just return `List<MainRepository>`

Comment: @Magnus I'm trying to do this since I have many different objects that all have the same methods implementation where only the type changes.

Comment: @Yoav, if that is the case. Why not make a Repository<T> subclass for each type of object? The data fetching logic can be in the base class. Edit: as suggested in Kjartan's answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you could do this, if that is a viable option for you?:

```
public class MainRepository<T>
{
    public List<T> GetAll()
    {
        return new List<T>();
    }
}
```

If I'm not mistaken, that should allow you to call the method without specifying the type in the method-call (though you obviously have to specify it for the class instead).

I'm assuming you want to do this in order to have some general generic repository, which can be sub-classed, or something similar? You could then do something like (just a rough idea):

```
public class BaseRepo {

}

public class MainRepository<T> : BaseRepo where T : BaseRepo{

    public List<T> GetAll(){
        return new List<T>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is only possible through reflection since the true type of an object is only known at runtime. Therefore, you have to design your method to return the common base class of all lists, which is object in .NET, and create the list in the method dynamically.

```
public object GetAll()
{
    return System.Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(this.GetType()));
}
```

However, I do not see why you would want to do that.